# Protocol buffers for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, gwt, protocol-buffers

Is there a way to do protocol buffers in JavaScript?

Why for .js?

If you think about sciencey requirements for a moment, situations pop up where you might want to send a large block of data to the client.  With CRUD-style it doesn't really matter so much what you use.  With sciencey stuff it does matter (at least I think it does).

tradeoffs:

- protobuffs balances compactness, serialize and deserialize speeds well.
- text based protocols (xml / json) have a larger message size... but with javascript I wonder which is more effective.

reference:

- code.google.com/p/protobuf-plugin-closure
- [Google Protocol Buffers or something similar for .net/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131504/google-protocol-buffers-or-something-similar-for-net-javascript)
- https://github.com/sirikata/protojs
- [Google Protocol Buffers - JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912981/google-protocol-buffers-javascript)
- http://www.vitaliykulikov.com/2011/02/gwt-friendly-protocol-buffers.html
- http://benhakala.blogspot.com/2010/05/converting-google-protocol-buffers-to.html (alludes to google maps possibly using protobufs)

Additional references provided by community (see below for more context):

- https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js
- http://blog.ltgt.net/exploring-using-protobuf-in-the-browser/
- http://blog.ltgt.net/using-protobuf-client-side-with-gwt
- http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-gwt/

Comment: ty. Added this as a reference.

Comment: I came across another Protocol Buffers for JavaScript project. It seems to be active and relies on Google's `closure` library: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-plugin-closure/

Comment: ty.  There's some interest out there for this at least.  I wonder sometimes why  people don't combine forces more.

Comment: @AndrewBarber upon review, perhaps your objection was that the question opened in a chatty way.  Since the question was first written, the JS community has evolved considerably.  However, first-class protobuffer support is still needed in JavaScript.  I think the question is still relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have been looking for protobuf for javascript. There is a project here:
https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js

Comment: thanks.  I'll keep an eye on this project.  In future I'd like to support something like this.  Fingers crossed that a capable library will emerge.

Comment: Nothing [changed](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-js/source/list) since the 0.0.0 release in 2008. Might still be okay, of course. Did you experiment with this?

Comment: Sorry,  haven't worked on this on a while.   Cannot answer much.   From what I remember it did what it advertised.  I don't have this in production so I cannot vouch for it with certainty.

Comment: This is the best js protobuf library I have found. Currently using it and it is working well.

Comment: Seems it's active recently (2014). With 11 releases, 21 open vs 127 closed issues, wiki seems not rich enough.

Answer (score 14):

Google makes heavy use of Protocol Buffers in JS (GMail, etc.) through their Closure Library, generating JS code with a (unfortunately non-open-sourced) modified `protoc` (it would probably have to be *ported* to a `protoc` extension before being open-sourced).

Apache Wave (whose *client* webapp is built with GWT) also uses Protocol Buffers for its communications with the server, generating Java code by reflecting on the Java classes produced by `protoc` (this is the PST, aka protobuf-stringtemplate, subproject).
Previously, Wave was using [protostuff](http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/) (and I don't know why they switched to their own solution, I suspect PST is derived from what the original Google Wave was using, and protostuff was only an intermediate step during the move to open-source).

As a side note, I started exploring using Protocol Buffers on the browser side a while ago: http://blog.ltgt.net/exploring-using-protobuf-in-the-browser/ & http://blog.ltgt.net/using-protobuf-client-side-with-gwt with some almost-working code at http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-gwt/ that you might want to resurrect.

Finally, there's work underway to make GWT RequestFactory proxies compatible with the server-side Java classes generated by `protoc` (and you could use a `protoc` extension or a similar approach to Wave's PST to generate your RequestFactory proxies). It should already be possible, provided you use builders all the way on the server-side (which is not quite how the Protocol Buffers Java API was designed).

Comment: I started thinking about the cross browser issues for a JavaScript version of protobufs.  Did you many issues with this in your testing?

Comment: We actually settled on a different architecture and aren't using Protocol Buffers at all, so there haven't been much testing per se. But most if not all of the cross-browser issues (related to encoding/decoding the messages to JSON and transporting your protobuf/json-encoded message (XMLHttpRequest)) would be taken care of by either Closure or GWT (or the JS lib of your choice).

Comment: sorry... switched from your informative answer to dcode's one.  Looks like the state of js proto is changing.

Answer (score 8):

Historically javascript made working with binary a pain, which probably in part explains a relative lack of tooling - but with javascript typed arrays it could well be a lot easier now. I kinda agree that if you *have* to get the same volume of data (via some format), using less bandwidth is a plus - but before embarking on anything you'd need to check that bandwidth / processing was an actual bottleneck (and if bandwidth: have you tried gzip/deflate first).

I'm a fan of protobuf - and I'd happily see stronger browser-side tooling for it, but json is so ubiquitous that you'd need a compelling reason to challenge the status-quo. Also; think "jsonp".

Comment: took a look at "jsonp".  Nice technique.  Thanks for the reminder on gzip... it seems a pity to introduce extra representations + steps.

Comment: @sgtz my point re jsonp is that jsonp solves a specific issue re same-origin; I'm not sure how you could address the same same-origin issue with raw data.