# How to stream an image from Python to C++ using Apache Thrift

Tags: c++, thrift, cpp-netlib

How could I stream files(images) using Apache Thrift?
I have searched a lot about Thrift and did not find any well written documentation regarding to it. Why did Facebook open sourced this project without docs?

Comment: "*did not find any well written documentation regarding to it*" - http://thrift.apache,org/docs and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift/20664706#20664706) don't fit your needs? "*Why did Facebook open sourced this project without docs*" - [They clearly didn't](https://thrift.apache.org/static/files/thrift-20070401.pdf). Maybe the Google index is outdated so you were not able to find those links?

Comment: I mean an API Doc listed classes and Methods

Comment: The Tutorials and the Test server/client pair do a much better job explaining Thrift than any API class list would do ever. I also highly recommend [Randy's forthcoming Thrift book](http://www.manning.com/abernethy/), already available via MEAP. More info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653240/what-is-rpc-framework-and-apache-thrift/20664706#20664706 - BTW, one of the links above is incorrect, it is http://thrift.apache.org/docs

Comment: Thanks @JensG, since I'm a newbie in network applications, I'm searching for more detail tutorial using Thrift.

Answer (score 4):

The way I would recommend is to set up your service to deliver data in chunks, like so:

```
struct DataChunk {
  1 : binary data
  2 : bool haveMoreData
}

service {
  DataChunk  GetChunk( 1 : string resource, 2: i32 offset, 3: i32 size)
}
```

It seems a good idea to either limit the `size` to some sane value (needs to be checked on the server side), or remove the `size` argument at all and always deliver chunks of a fixed, predefined size to circumvent clients asking for insanely large data blocks.

Note that the whole process needs to follow the pull model, there is no built-in push feature. However, you still can do push, you just need to run a Thrift server on the client side and pass the necessary connection info. Although this will not work in all scenarios (especially transports), it is a fully working solution where it is possible.